# Calculate the sum of a query that uses order by and limit Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

The following query returns a table of grades.
I want the sum of it and i cant figure out how to do it.

```
SELECT grade
 FROM "GradesTable"
 WHERE status='success' AND student_ID=1
 ORDER BY grade DESC
 LIMIT 50
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  column "grade" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used
>   in an aggregate function

Comment: The error i get comes from this query:
SELECT SUM(grade) FROM "GradesTable" WHERE status='success' AND student_ID=1 ORDER BY grade DESC LIMIT 50

Comment: The query you have shown will **not** produce that error. Please [edit] your question and add the real query. Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's not true, see the `ORDER BY`. This is the first time I think you were wrong about something even tangentially related to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: see here: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4c4dccb4d348f7b9b1f9908abe5254f6

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah I see. I just read that to mean *when I make this sum(grade)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the `ORDER BY` clause which you would know if you pasted the full error, instead of forcing us to recreate your problem from scratch because you didn't provide the DDL and data.

```
CREATE TABLE "GradesTable" ( status text, student_id int, grade int );
INSERT INTO "GradesTable" (status, student_id, grade) VALUES
  ('success', 1, 80),
  ('success', 1, 100);
```

Query

```
SELECT sum(grade)                                                    FROM "GradesTable"
 WHERE status='success' AND student_ID=1
 ORDER BY grade DESC
 LIMIT 50
;
ERROR:  column "GradesTable.grade" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 4:  ORDER BY grade DESC
```

However this works,

```
SELECT sum(grade)
 FROM "GradesTable"
 WHERE status='success' AND student_ID=1
 LIMIT 50
;
 sum 
-----
 180
(1 row)
```

But you shouldn't have a `LIMIT` if you have only one agg that can only ever return one row.

```
SELECT sum(grade)
 FROM "GradesTable"
 WHERE status='success' AND student_ID=1
;
```

If you meant to order by `sum(grade)` you can do that, but you lose the ability to order by `grade` the second you aggregate it together. However, in this example it doesn't matter because you're only returning one row.

**And as a separate note you should never quote identifiers in PostgreSQL. Make everything lowercase, never quote table names or column names.**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(grades)
FROM
(
SELECT grade as grades
FROM "GradesTable"
 WHERE status='success' AND student_ID=1
 ORDER BY grade DESC
 LIMIT 50
) z
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation as to why this is the correct answer.  Code-only answers do not tend to educate readers.